# AngularJS controller init

Tags: angularjs

Angular JS Newbie: I get the `gapi is not defined` because `sydney.userAuthed` is called before the API is loaded. But I don't understand why the method `sydney.auth` is called when the controller is created. I get the error when the page loads, there is no user interaction.

```
calling auth api.js:22
ReferenceError: gapi is not defined
    at Object.sydney.userAuthed (http://localhost:8888/js/api.js:36:8)
    at Object.sydney.auth (http://localhost:8888/js/api.js:23:30)
    at new LoginController (http://localhost:8888/js/controllers.js:8:24)
    at invoke (http://localhost:8888/lib/angular/angular.js:2902:28)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:8888/lib/angular/angular.js:2914:23)
    at http://localhost:8888/lib/angular/angular.js:4805:24
    at updateView (http://localhost:8888/lib/angular/angular-ui-router.js:931:30)
    at <error: illegal access>
    at Object.Scope.$broadcast (http://localhost:8888/lib/angular/angular.js:8307:28)
    at $state.transition.resolved.then.$state.transition (http://localhost:8888/lib/angular/angular-ui-router.js:747:20) angular.js:5754
OAuth2 API loaded api.js:13
```

I defined a `state` with `ui-router` as:

```
myapp.config(function($stateProvider, $routeProvider) {

    $stateProvider.state('signin', {
        url : "/", // root route
        views : {
            "signinView" : {
                templateUrl : 'partials/signin.html',
                controller: 'LoginController'
            }
        },
    })
```

The controller is defined as:

```
function LoginController($scope, $state) {
  $scope.auth = sydney.auth($state);
}
```

`sydney.auth` method is used to authenticate a user using `Google APIs Client Library for JavaScript`.

```
var sydney = sydney || {};

sydney.auth = function($state) {
    console.log("calling auth");
    sydney.signin(false, sydney.userAuthed($state));
}

sydney.signin = function(mode, callback) {
      gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: sydney.CLIENT_ID,
        scope: sydney.SCOPES, immediate: mode,
        response_type: 'token id_token'},
        callback);
      console.log("signin called");
}

sydney.userAuthed = function($state) { 
      var request =
          gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get().execute(function(resp) {
        if (!resp.code) {
          var token = gapi.auth.getToken();
          token.access_token = token.id_token;
          gapi.auth.setToken(token);
          // User is signed in, call my Endpoint
          gapi.client.realestate.owner.create().execute(function(resp) {
              alert("Signed In");
              $state.transitionTo("signedin");
            });
        }
      });
    }
```

**EDIT**

The correct answer is to define `$scope.auth` as a function:

```
function LoginController($scope, $state) {
  $scope.auth = function() { 
      sydney.auth($state);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a plunker for this? You can try to add gapi to function variables like this function($state, gapi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems what you're trying to do is make the `sydney.auth` function available from your scope. If so, you should change your `LoginController` to:

```
function LoginController($scope, $state) {
  $scope.auth = sydney.auth;
}
```

What your code was doing was calling the `sydney.auth` function and setting `$scope.auth` to its return value, which is not what I think you intended.

Comment: Answer accepted because it helped me to find the right solution. Question edited with the correct answer.